# How to use classpath in ubuntu terminal for executing java class?

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I tried to execute CreateTextFileTest.class file with classpath in the terminal as the following:

```
java -classpath ..:"/home/fatih/NetBeansProjects/Unit17 - CreatingTextFile/src/unit17/unit17/creatingtextfile" CreateTextFileTest
```

My class files in this directory : `/home/fatih/NetBeansProjects/Unit17 - CreatingTextFile/src/unit17/unit17/creatingtextfile` .

I have 3 classes in the directory: `AccountRecord.class` , `CreateTextFile.class`, and `CreateTextFileTest.class`

But, when I executed the CreateTextFileTest from the terminal with the code above, an error occured like that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CreateTextFileTest (**wrong name**: unit17/creatingtextfile/CreateTextFileTest)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

As far as I understand because `CreateTextFileTest.java` uses two different classes, executing fails. How to handle this situation? How to run my java project? How to use classpath in this situation? Am I using wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the package name declared in your compiled class doesn't match what the JVM was expecting given your classpath setup. The classpath should point to the directory from which your packages start, not the directory actually containing your `.class` files. Given your error message I believe that this should work:

```
java -classpath ..:"/home/fatih/NetBeansProjects/Unit17 - CreatingTextFile/src/unit17" unit17.creatingtextfile.CreateTextFileTest
```

Given the duplicate `unit17` in your path I get the impression there's something else mixed up here. You'll get a better answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)...